# Looking for an equivalent for UIWebViewDelegate for porting an iOS app to OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, ios, uiwebview, webkit

I'm trying to port an iOS App to OSX and there is one thing I don't get. The iOS app uses UIWebView, to be more precise a UIView the implements the UIWebViewDelegate:

```
@interface Dialog : UIView <UIWebViewDelegate> {
```

and implements those three delegate Methods:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request

  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
```

Can someone give me a hint how I can port this to the normal OSX Framework? I know there is the WebView but it has 4 Delegates as far as I could figure it out and none of these has delegate Methods that sounds like those 3.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first one, you'll probably want to use a [WebPolicyDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). And for the other two, there are corresponding methods in [WebFrameLoadDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the iOS `UIWebView` `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, to accomplish this using the OSX `WebView`:

Set the [WebPolicyDelegate delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for your WebView instance:

```
self.webview.policyDelegate = self;
```

Then implement the `– webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` method in your delegate:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame
decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    int actionKey = [[actionInformation objectForKey: WebActionNavigationTypeKey] intValue];
    if (actionKey == WebNavigationTypeOther)
    {
        [listener use];
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // Here is where you would intercept the user navigating away 
        // from the current page, and use `[listener ignore];`
        //

        NSLog(@"\n\nuser navigating from: \n\t%@\nto:\n\t%@",
              [webView mainFrameURL],
              [[request URL] absoluteString]);

        [listener use];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
       request:(NSURLRequest *)request
         frame:(WebFrame *)frame
decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener

I am using this instead of shouldStartLoadWithRequest, this is working well